# NSTextField in statsbar menu becomes unresponsive after clicking outside the menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsmenu

I'm building a statusbar menu using custom views, and everything seems to work fine except for text fields. The first time I open the menu, everything works fine. If I close the menu by clicking the statusbar icon again, it also continues to work fine.

If I close it by clicking outside the menu, however, the next time I open the menu the text fields will be completely unresponsive. I can sometimes highlight the NSTextField, and even make the "itemEdited" event happen.

Any ideas on this weird issue? Buttons put on the same view work fine.

I've made a sample project to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/Nic0S/NSTextField-bug

Comment: try to make the text field first responder explicitly

Comment: Can you go into more detail on how? I'm really new to cocoa apps!

More details: The view is defined in a .xib, and the file owner is set to my custom NSViewController class.

Comment: The view is implicitly attached to a window. Send the method `makeFirstResponder` with parameter the instance of the text field to this window.

Comment: I added the following

`[[nameField window] makeFirstResponder:nameField];

 [[codeField window] makeFirstResponder:codeField];`

in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller, still has the same issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even if I construct a new menu, menu item, and view controller every time it's opened..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I eventually gave up up on using buttons within the menu, I likely would have had to extend the NSTextField class and reimplement a bunch of stuff, because I think this is bug on Apple's end.